# How to extend core templates in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, extend

How to extend `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml` so I can add another button to it?

I tried it by creating my own module and copied the above file to `app/code/"vendorname"/"modulename"/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml` and created an xml file `app/code/"vendorname"/"modulename"/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml` that has the following content:

```
               <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart">
                    <action method="setTemplate">

                         <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Rampart_Core::form.phtml</argument>

                    </action>
               </referenceBlock>
```

But it override the cart page and display only a portion of the `original-cart page` whereas I want to add button to existing cart page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple to extend form.

Here you can extend: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml`

Extend it same: `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/Theme_Name/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml`

-- you only need to update :VENDOR/Theme_Name

This is suffice if you only to update button in form.phtml and there is no need to extend/overwrite module for it.

Comment: It's not working. Cart page is empty now

Comment: I hope you have extend theme ? And after above edit: You need to delete your module. And run upgrade and compile commands. It must work.